# "inclusive of" and "including"

Tags: synonyms, register

Are "inclusive of" and "including" interchangeable in the following?

> a. We all liked the show, **inclusive of** / **including** Sarah.
>
> b. Five passengers were injured in the accident, **inclusive of** / **including** a pregnant woman.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use **inclusive of** when formally predicating something of something:

> *Eudaimonia* is inclusive of all intrinsic goods.

The phrase *is inclusive of* is in a formal register that says "I'm making a (careful) predication", although some people might think it says "I'm a windbag who avoids simple verbs like **includes**".

Use **including** when tacking on an adjunct clause:

> These rules must be followed by everyone, including you.